# Output execution time for a Playwright step with AJAX payload

Tags: javascript, playwright

I am trying to dump out a few key measurements to console when my test runs, rather than getting them from the reporter output, but I can't see how to grab the time taken for the last step to execute. Here's a simplified version based on the docs for request.timing() but I don't think that what I'm doing is classed as a request:

```
const { test, expect } = require('@playwright/test');

test('ApplicationLoadTime', async ({ page }) => {

  // Wait for applications to load
  await page.waitForSelector('img[alt="Application"]');

  // Not working! - get time for step execution
  const [fir] = await Promise.all([
    page.click('text=Further information requested'),
    page.waitForSelector('img[alt="Application"]')
  ]);
  console.log(fir.timing());

});
```

The click on "Further information requested" causes the page to be modified based on an AJAX call in the background and the appearance of the Application img tells me it's finished. Is this possible or do I need to rely on the reports instead?

Comment: Update: Possibly a documentation issue? The documentation example:

https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-request#request-timing

suggests that I can use console.log(fir.timing());, but it seems to need console.log(fir.request().timing());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fir` is going to be `undefined` in your code as `page.click()` doesn't return anything. You need to wait for the request whose timing you're interested in, use [`page.waitForEvent('requestfinished')`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-event-request-finished) or [`waitForNavigation`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-navigation):

```js
const { test, expect } = require('@playwright/test');

test('ApplicationLoadTime', async ({ page }) => {

  // Wait for applications to load
  await page.waitForSelector('img[alt="Application"]');

  const [fir] = await Promise.all([
    // Wait for the request
    page.waitForEvent('requestfinished', r => r.url() == '<url of interest>'),
    page.click('text=Further information requested'),
    page.waitForSelector('img[alt="Application"]')
  ]);
  console.log(fir.timing());

});
```